# Vis.js dual y axis data range issue

Tags: javascript, graph, vis.js

```
<head>
  <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
  <title>Graph2d | Basic Example</title>

  <style type="text/css">
    body, html {
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
  </style>

    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.15.1/vis.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.15.1/vis.min.js"></script>

<body>
<h2>Graph2d | Basic Example</h2>
<br />
<div id="visualization"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var container = document.getElementById('visualization');
    var names = ['graph1', 'graph2'];
    var groups = new vis.DataSet();
    groups.add({
        id: 0,
        className: '',
        options: {
            yAxisOrientation: 'left',
            drawPoints: {
                style: 'point' // square, circle
            }
        }});
    groups.add({
        id: 1,
        className: '',
        options: {
            yAxisOrientation: 'right', // right, left
            drawPoints: {
                style: 'circle' // square, circle
            }
        }});

  var items = [
    {x: new Date(1469626499397), y: 110, group: 0},
    {x: new Date(1469626499497), y: 125, group: 0},
    {x: new Date(1469626499597), y: 130, group: 0},
    {x: new Date(1469626499697), y: 210, group: 0},
    {x: new Date(1469626499897), y: 115, group: 0},
    {x: new Date(1469626499997), y: 130, group: 0},
    {x: new Date(1469626499397), y: 1, group: 1},
    {x: new Date(1469626499597), y: 2, group: 1},
    {x: new Date(1469626499697), y: 3, group: 1},
    {x: new Date(1469626499797), y: 10, group: 1},
    {x: new Date(1469626499897), y: 15, group: 1},
    {x: new Date(1469626499997), y: 10, group: 1}
  ];

  var dataset = new vis.DataSet(items);
  var options = {
  height:500,
  //graphHeight:1500,
          drawPoints: true,
        dataAxis: {
            right: {
                range: {min:-1, max:20}
            },
            left: {
                range: {min:100, max:250}
            },
            icons:true
        },
  };
  var graph2d = new vis.Graph2d(container, dataset, groups, options);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ug11.png
In the image, right side y axis is not showing  grid line less than 5 and more than 12.

I am facing issue here is right side y axis is not taking data range properly and hide graph even though right side data range starts with minimum value 1 and maximum value 15.

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this issue is seeing in vis.js release 4.13.0 onwards.
Dual y-axis is working as expecting in 4.12.0 version release.